# ui router ng click event not fired

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have an ng-click method within a state which is not getting fired. I tried attaching the event to the `$rootScope` object, but the result is still not getting fired.

HTML :

```
<div id="wrapper" class="toggled">
    <div id="sidebar-wrapper" ng-show="showMenu">
        <ul class="sidebar-nav">
            <li class="sidebar-brand">
                <a href="#">Test 1</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div><!-- #sidebar-wrapper -->

    <div id="page-content-wrapper">
        <div class="container">
            <div ui-view></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <button type="button" id="menu-toggle" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="toggleMenu()" ng-show="showMenuBtn">Menu</button>
</div><!-- wrapper -->
```

JS -

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.router']);

app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');

$stateProvider
.state('login', {
    url : '/login',
    templateUrl : 'login.html',
    controller : function ($scope, $http, $state, $rootScope){

        //menu visbility toggle
        $rootScope.showMenu = false

        //show menu button
        $rootScope.showMenuBtn = false

        //login functionality.
        $scope.login = function(){
            if ($scope.formdata.username != "" && $scope.formdata.password != "")
            {
                $http.post('/login', $scope.formdata)
                .success(function (data){
                    console.log(data)
                    if (data.loginFlag){
                        $state.go('main')
                    }
                })
                .error(function (data){
                    console.log("Error", data)
                });
            } else {

            }
        }

        //changing state to signup
        $scope.goToSignUp = function(){
            $state.go('signup')
        }
    }
})

.state('signup',{
    url: '/signup',
    templateUrl: 'signup.html',
    controller: function ($scope, $http, $state){

        //changing state to login
        $scope.goBackToSign = function(){
            $state.go('login')
        }
    }
})

.state('main',{
    url: '/main',
    templateUrl: 'main.html',
    controller: function ($scope, $http, $state, $rootScope){

        //menu visibility toggle
        $rootScope.showMenu = true

        //show menu button
        $rootScope.showMenuBtn = true

        //toggle class for menu display/no display
        $scope.toggleMenu = function()
        {
            angular.element(document.getElementById(wrapper)).toggleClass('toggled');
        }

    }
})
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use ng-class on angular. The second problem was that you were using

```
$scope.toggle = true;
```

You can't access that $scope because that scope is from the controller when you call main.html so you can't access it outside your controller like you were trying (outside the ui-view).

That's why your solution using $rootScope worked and will work if you use my above solution but doing

```
...
$rootScope.toggle = true;
//toggle class for menu display/no display
$rootScope.toggleMenu = function()
{
    $rootScope.toggle = !$rootScope.toggle;
}
...
```

But that is just bad practice.
Like I said above you really should read that angular style guide by John Papa and you should do those stuffs in your code to make more readable and understandable, like naming controllers etc etc.

So when you want to access a variable outside your controller you should create a service or a factory for that.
So I'll just show you what I did to your code and if you have some doubt just comment :D

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="app">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <title>Login App</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">   </script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.15/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/bootstrap.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/style.css"/>

</head>
<body ng-controller="AppController as appCtrl">

    <div id="wrapper" ng-class="{'toggled': menuUtil.toggle}">
         <div id="sidebar-wrapper" ng-show="menuUtil.showMenu">
            <ul class="sidebar-nav">
                <li class="sidebar-brand">
                    <a href="#">Test 1</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
         </div><!-- #sidebar-wrapper -->

         <div id="page-content-wrapper">
             <div class="container">
                 <div ui-view></div>
             </div>
         </div>
    </div><!-- wrapper -->

    <script src="/js/app.controller.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/menuUtil.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

main.html:

```
<button type="button" id="menu-toggle" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="toggleMenu()" ng-show="menuUtil.showMenuBtn">Menu</button>
```

app.js:

```
 (function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app', ['ui.router'])
        .config(configure);

    function configure($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');

        $stateProvider.state('login', {
            url : '/login',
            templateUrl : 'login.html',
            controller : function ($scope, $http, $state, $rootScope){

                //login functionality.
                $scope.login = function(){
                    if ($scope.formdata.username != "" && $scope.formdata.password != "")
                    {
                        $http.post('/login', $scope.formdata)
                        .success(function (data){
                            console.log(data)
                            if (data.loginFlag){
                                $state.go('main')
                            }
                        })
                        .error(function (data){
                            console.log("Error", data)
                        });
                    } else {

                    }
                }

                //changing state to signup
                $scope.goToSignUp = function(){
                    $state.go('signup')
                }
            }
        })

        .state('signup',{
            url: '/signup',
            templateUrl: 'signup.html',
            controller: function ($scope, $http, $state){

                //changing state to login
                $scope.goBackToSign = function(){
                    $state.go('login')
                }
            }
        })

        .state('main',{
            url: '/main',
            templateUrl: 'main.html',
            //inject menuUtil so that you can use below on controller
            resolve: {
                menuUtil: 'menuUtil'
            },
            controller: function ($scope, $http, $state, menuUtil){

                $scope.menuUtil = menuUtil;

                //toggle class for menu display/no display
                $scope.toggleMenu = function() {
                    menuUtil.toggle = !menuUtil.toggle;
                };
            }
        });
    }
})();
```

I added app.controller.js so that you could access the factory as well outside the ui-view
app.controller.js:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .controller('AppController', AppController);

    AppController.$inject = ['$scope', 'menuUtil'];
    function AppController ($scope, menuUtil) {
        $scope.menuUtil = menuUtil;
    }

})();
```

And also added the factory to provide this menu information to where you need it in your app
menuUtil.js:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .factory('menuUtil', menuUtil);

    function menuUtil () {
        var toggle = true;
        var showMenu = true;
        var showMenuBtn = true;

        var service = {
            showMenu: showMenu,
            showMenuBtn: showMenuBtn,
            toggle: toggle
        };

        return service;
    }

})();
```

As you can see I made some changes to the styling, and it still can be a lot better. Don't just do code, do it beautifully hehe :D GL hope I helped

Comment: Is there someplace I could share my code with you? It would be nice to receive some pointers that you have added here. LinkedIn? Gmail? something of that sort.
Also, the reason I added class="toggle" on #wrapper is because there was some animation happening when using ng-class. I'm assuming this is because there is a difference in time when class and ng-class are rendered.

Comment: I downloaded your code and put it working the way I showed you here, but if you want to chat or something you can add me on google and we can use hangouts to chat. I can also send you the code as I changed. fredericojesus88@gmail.com

Answer (score 1):

In angularjs you should use [ng-class](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) to toggle classes.

So you could do something like this

HTML:

```
//ng-class="{'<class name>': <statement>}" 
//class is applied if the statement occurs (or is true)
<div id="wrapper" ng-class="{'toggled': toggle}">
    ...
</div><!-- wrapper -->
```

JS (inside your controller):

```
...
$scope.toggle = true;
//toggle class for menu display/no display
$scope.toggleMenu = function()
{
    $scope.toggle = !$scope.toggle;
}
...
```

I advise you also to read more in the AngularJS documentation in the link I posted above for ng-class, there's a lot you can learn there.
And also this [style guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide) by John Papa, very cool stuff!

Comment: I tried using ng-class to toggle the menu animation. However, on the first page load there is an animation that is taking place when using ng-class instead of class. If you're curious, you can look at the github project [here](https://github.com/tarang9211/NodeLogin/tree/master/loginapp)

Comment: If you want people to help you on github you should only have your project in the repository, and you have a lot of projects.
Create a new repository with your project only so I can clone it and please also remove node modules from it, we can quickly install them via npm
add 
node_modules/ 
to .gitignore

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've misplaced a bracket.

Instead of

```
angular.element($('#wrapper').toggleClass('toggled'));
```

Try

```
angular.element(document.getElementById(wrapper)).toggleClass('toggled');
```

Comment: i tried this, but the event is still not being fired.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using ng-class?

```
<div id="page-content-wrapper" ng-class="{ 'toggled': isToggled }">
```

Then in your controller:

```
$scope.isToggled = false;
$scope.toggleMenu = function() {
    $scope.isToggled = !$scope.isToggled;
}
```

https://scotch.io/tutorials/the-many-ways-to-use-ngclass

Comment: yes, but the toggleMenu function itself is not being fired.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put our button within ui-view to get it working although its not a right way to do routing.

```
   <div ui-view>
            <button type="button" id="menu-toggle" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="toggleMenu()" ng-show="showMenuBtn">Menu</button>
   </div>
```

**Update :** Please see the plunker i create for you to know how to get your work done with proper routing.

http://plnkr.co/edit/1sRSWcG2JInyvSEiSOJ8?p=preview